# Android ProgressDialog showing but progress not updated

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am trying to update the progress bar after creation (both in AsyncTask). The progress dialog shows up and dismisses but not updated, it is always set to 0. Here is my code:
    public class ImageTask extends AsyncTask
    {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... saleId) {

        //Drawable drawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sale_image_holder);
        //Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        //ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        //byte[] imageInAsByteArray = stream.toByteArray(); // here
        ImgService imgService = new ImgService();
        imgService.addImgToSale(imageInAsByteArray, saleId[0], this);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void doProgress(int value){
        publishProgress(value);
    }
}
```

here is the ImgService class:

```
public class ImgService 
{
    public void addImgToSale(byte[] img, final String saleId, final ImageTask task)
    {
        final ParseFile file = new ParseFile(saleId + ".jpeg", img);
        try {
            file.save();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        task.doProgress(50);
        ParseObject image = new ParseObject(DBDictionary.SALE_IMAGES);
        ParseObject sale = new ParseObject(DBDictionary.SALE);
        sale.setObjectId(saleId);
        image.put(DBDictionary.SALE_IMAGES_SALE_ID_P, ParseObject.createWithoutData(DBDictionary.SALE, saleId));
        image.put("image", file);
        try {
            image.save();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        task.doProgress(100);
    }
}
```

In the net I found many problems with showing and dismissing the ProgressDialog but not with the progress updating.

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress. call public progress in doInbackground

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From android doc: use onProgressUpdate function inside your asynctask.

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
  protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));//this function updates the progress bar ...
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

Comment: how dose `publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));//this function updates the progress bar ...` connected to my dialog?

Comment: it calls the `onProgressUpdate` method which uses the args to `setProgressPercent` inshaa Allaah

Answer (score 3):

Refer the code below

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {   

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

    try {

    URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
    conexion.connect();

    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
    FileOutputStream obj;
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    String Path="/sdcard/";

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Path+"some_photo_from_gdansk_poland.jpg");

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

    long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

}
```

Add in manifest **android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

Comment: the compiler dose not recognize `publishProgress`

Answer (score 1):

Remove your  `dialog.setProgress(50)` line from postexecute method and use below code into asynctask.

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
                    {
                       dialog.setProgress(values[0]);    
                    }
```

Comment: when I put (for example) `publishProgress(20);` in my `doInBackground` the compiler giving me an error. Why?

Comment: I did this. You can see it in my question. the error that I am getting is: `The method publishProgress(R.integer...) in the type AsyncTask<Void,R.integer,String> is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Comment: the error is gone, but the program not enters to the `onProgressUpdate` method. You can see the edited code in my question.

Comment: change datatype from int to Integer .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31385/discussion-between-segi-and-vlad-ioffe)

Answer (score 0):

Setting "indeterminate" to false did the trick for me:

```
dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate(boolean)